# type casting in objective-c, (NSInteger) VS. integerValue

Tags: ios, xcode, casting

I don't very understand about the diference between `(NSInteger)aNumberValue` and `[aNumberValue integerValue]`, then do some test. For example, here is a response data from server:

[image]

You can see it's an int but the value is hold by NSNumber. I retrieve the data by writting `NSInteger count = (NSInteger) dic[@"count"];`, and in Xcode debug area, saw this:

[image]

it's really a strange value but when I run `po count` and saw this:

[image]

anyway, the value is correct, but another strange thing is:

[image]

the number 2 is not less than 100!

Then I try `NSInteger a = [dic[@"count"] integerValue]` and saw the normal value in Xcode debug area:

[image]

and:

[image]

So, I am a little bit confused, what's the deference between `(NSInteger)aNumberValue` and `[aNumberValue integerValue]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNumber` is a class; `NSInteger` is just a `typedef` of `long`, which is a primitive type.

`dic[@"count"]` is a pointer, which means that `dic[@"count"]` holds an address that points to the `NSNumber` instance. `NSNumber` has a method called `integerValue` which returns an `NSInteger` as the underlying value that the `NSNumber` instance represents. So you can conclude that `[dic[@"count"] integerValue]` gets you a `long`, and that's how you retrieve the value out of `NSNumber`.

You don't retrieve the value of `NSNumber` by casting it to `NSInteger`. That's because `dic[@"count"]`, as I said, is a pointer. So by writing

```
NSInteger count = (NSInteger) dic[@"count"];
```

you are actually casting the pointer *itself* to an `NSInteger`, which has nothing to do with the actual represented value. The value `402008592` you see is just a decimal representation of the value of the pointer, which is an address.

The command `po` is used for printing *objects*, so lldb will actually try to print out the object at the address of `count`. That's why you get `2` back using `po`. You can try `p count` and you'll get `402008592`.

About `po count < 100`: The expression `(count < 100)` is evaluated first; since `count` is really just an `NSInteger` of `402008592`, it will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The root issue is that Objective-C collection classes can only store Objective-C objects, not primitive types like `float`, `int` or `NSInteger`.

Therefore `NSNumber` provides a mechanism to store numbers and booleans in object form.

The value `402008592` looks like an address, so it's probably an `NSNumber` object containing an `NSInteger` value.

Don't get confused by the `NS` prefix of `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger`; they are still primitive types and not objects like `NSNumber`.

Comment: Why does `count<100` return false?

Comment: @Allen I'm no expert with llvm, but `po` simply prints a description of an object; I don't believe it can be used to evaluate expressions like that.